# Unit test on simple method which only calls other method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testcase, test-coverage

If a public method only calls external methods and contains no special logic within, should I add unit test on it?

The method below only calls external methods and use return values to construct a student object.

```
public student GetStudent(int ID){
    var n = GetName(ID);
    var a = GetAddress(ID);
    return new student{
        name  = n;
        address = a;
    }
}
```

If I have a separate set of unit tests on GetName() and GetAddress() method already, do I still need to have unit tests on GetStudent() method?

Since tests already ensure GetName() and GetAddress() will return valid result(e.g. not null), GetStudent() should be fine accordingly.

I find it is rather difficult to decide whether I should do test on a method or not. May you also recommend some external resources (e.g. website, book, blog) on this regards?

Thank you.

Comment: Ideally, yes. Tests are to future-proof code, not to test it as-is. What if `GetStudent` changes its logic to return `name = n.ToLower()` by another developer, breaking multiple things?

Comment: Additionaly to @Rob's answer - if you expose the student data using the `student` class, do you need public `GetName` and `GetAddress`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify GetStudent behavior in test. for example what should happen in case of unreal id? exeption/null this should be described in test. you need to check final objct: can/cant name be null, can/cant address be null. it will be good documentation for GetStudent function

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "primarily opinion-based" but in common, you can test this method and check:

1. Method does not return `null`
2. All fields of `student` class are set
3. You should mock `GetName` and `GetAddress` method and check that both of them are called with correct argument

So, this example is very simple, yes. But, maybe in future, you'll have some logic in this method and you need to ensure that everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

It's my philosophy that I always unit test methods that are exposed, no matter how trivial they are. Reason is if someone else is going to be working on this code, and they decide they want to change things, there is no Quality Assurance that their new code will break the system, unless you have Unit Tests. Unit Tests are there to make to make sure the code is of good quality and to make sure that other developers don't inherently break the system.